# Images Stored in RSS?

Tags: iphone, ios, rss, blogs, parent-child

I see so many apps for blogs like Engadget that all have different pictures from each article that are displayed within the TableView.  I use WordPress for my blog, and would love if the pictures that I post in each blog were added to the RSS Feed, like say the first image.  Any ways to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RSS feed should have an element that points to an image url. You just need to tear down the XML and figure out what element name the image (if it exists) is located in, then use the image as you would any other.

Comment: I guess I should edit the question about adding that field to an RSS using Wordpress